# Fill column with element of highest priority in that column

Tags: sql, oracle

Having a specified order: max > avg > min (**list**: **[max,avg,min]**), how can I fill a column with the element with the highest priority available in that column?

E.g.: C = the column name, T = table name

### (1)

Input:

```
C
--
min
max
avg
avg
max
```

Output:

```
max
max
max
max
max
```

## (2)

Input:

```
C
--
min
avg
min
```

Output:

```
avg
avg
avg
```

## (3)

Input:

```
C
--
min
min
```

Output:

```
min
min
```

I've tried to use `case` to establish the order above, but I wasn't able to build the full query.

I want a solution that works using pure SQL, not PL/SQL.

Comment: What do you mean "first value in the list"?  SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no "first" value, unless you have another column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: The list is not in the SQL table, it is specified separately. I emphasized it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`FIRST_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions066.htm#i83212) analytic function:

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE( C )
         OVER ( ORDER BY CASE C WHEN 'max' THEN 3
                                WHEN 'avg' THEN 2
                                WHEN 'min' THEN 1
                                ELSE 0 END DESC )
FROM   T;
```

If the list is being supplied dynamically then you could use:

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE( C )
         OVER ( ORDER BY CASE INSTR( :list, C )
                              WHEN 0 THEN NULL
                              ELSE INSTR( :list, C ) END ASC NULLS LAST )
FROM   T;
```

I.e. if you set `:list := 'max,avg,min';` then it will give the same results as the first query.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know anything about the `FIRST_VALUE` function.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you just want a special ordering based on max > avg > min.  You can do this with a `case` statement and window functions:

```
select (case when overall_priority = 3 then 'max'
             when overall_priority = 2 then 'avg'
             when overall_priority = 1 then 'min'
        end) as newcol
from (select t.*,
             max(case when c = 'max' then 3
                      when c = 'avg' then 2
                      when c = 'min' then 1
                  end) over () as overall_priority
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Your answer is great, but I've chosen the other one because it is shorter. Just one upvote for this. :) Thanks!

Comment: @helpYou .  . . I had thought about the version `min(instr('maxavgmin')) over ()` (and similar changes to the outside, but thought that overly clever.  In any case, the OP has the right (responsibility?) to accept one answer, and the answer you chose is quite reasonable and an interesting approach.